# functions depending on iterables

Tags: python, function

```
funcs = []
for i in range(3):
    a = i
    func = lambda x: a
    funcs.append(func)

print [func(0) for func in funcs]
```

I would like this to print `[0,1,2]`, instead it prints `[2,2,2]`.  I see what's going on, the question is how do I circumvent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get around this by binding `a` to the local scope of the `lambda` using a keyword argument:

```
funcs = []
for i in range(3):
    a = i
    func = lambda x, a=a: a
    funcs.append(func)
print [func(0) for func in funcs]
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
func = lambda x: a
```

states that you want the function to return `a` no matter what you pass it.

So when you call the functions with the argument `0`, it returns the value of `a`. Which is `2` after it exited from the for loop.

To circumvent that you would need to change the lambda function to:

```
func = lambda x: x
```

and change the following line:

```
print [func(0) for func in funcs]
```

to:

```
print [func(x) for x in range(3)]
```

Or bind `a` to the local scope of lambda as suggested by @dano.

Comment: How can I augment this so that the output of each function I append to the list is dependent on the utterable?